# Overwrite .Net Core "CultureInfo" after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cultureinfo, asp.net-core-localization

My application is working well with new cultures! So far so good!

But... I want overwrite the actual "**CultureInfo**" after the user is logged in. I have to do this because i need to reset the "**CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat**" with other one saved in my DB. Every user have a different "DateTimeFormat" for this reason i have to do this after login! For example on my controller "AccountController"

**Startup - Configure**:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Name"),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Startup - ConfigureServices**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        // Add localization services.
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            opts =>
            {
                var cultureList = new List<string>();
                Configuration.GetSection("Culture:Languages").Bind(cultureList);
                var supportedCultures = cultureList.Select(lang => new CultureInfo(lang)).ToList();

                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Culture:Default"));
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
                {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
                })
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
    }
```

**AccountController**:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Validation credentials
            var resultDto = await Repository.Get(model);

            if (resultDto.Errors != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = _localizer["Token.Invalid"];
                return View();
            }

            // Reset the CultureInfo
            ...

            return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Dashboard");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you store the localization as a claim and use/add `CustomRequestCultureProvider` to your list of providers?

Comment: I can save the user culture as a claim after the logged in... but... how can i use `CustomRequestCultureProvider` after the login?

Comment: One simple solution is to set the user culture to the thread. It's not really the most elegant solution, but it's pretty bullet-proof and easy to code. `Thread.CurrentCulture` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This solution doesn't work to .Net Core! Why Microsoft why.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you can read it from claims. Just make sure your `CustomRequestCultureProvider` is added first `.Insert(0, ...)` so it's called before the other providers.

In this example the claim is named `culture`.

```
// Add localization services.
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    opts =>
    {
        var cultureList = new List<string>();
        Configuration.GetSection("Culture:Languages").Bind(cultureList);
        var supportedCultures = cultureList.Select(lang => new CultureInfo(lang)).ToList();

        opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Culture:Default"));
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        // We add the CustomRequestCultureProvider first, so it's evaluated
        // Before the other 3 (Cookie, Header, Query) 
        localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0,
            new CustomRequestCultureProvider(httpContext =>
            {
                // When user is not logged in, return null and another
                // CultureProvider may try it's luck
                if (httpContext.User == null)
                    return null;

                // When no claim is set, also return it
                var culture = httpContext.User.FindFirst("culture");
                if (culture?.Value == null)
                    return null;

                // Here we set the language from the claim, since the result is not null
                // other providers won't be evaluated anymore and this language will be chosen
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(culture.Value));
            })
        );
    });
```